# Is there a better way to edit kafka topics with its message expiration interval?

Tags: go, apache-kafka, sarama

with the golang library sarama, is there a way to create a topic with a specific expiration time (for messages)?

And later that we can edit it, without deleting and recreating the topic?

Answer (score 2):

A [`ClusterAdmin`](https://godoc.org/github.com/Shopify/sarama#ClusterAdmin) client can create topics that have [`TopicDetail`](https://godoc.org/github.com/Shopify/sarama#TopicDetail)s containing a map of config entries, of which you can set the retention period

You can later edit it with [`AlterConfigsRequest`](https://github.com/Shopify/sarama/blob/master/alter_configs_request_test.go#L79)

Comment: Hi @cricket_007 thx for the info!

however, it seems that retention refers to logs instead of messages. The message itself wont be clean after xxx ms?

Comment: Messages are stored in logs. All messages older than the log retention time from which they are written will be cleaned from any closed log segments. In other words, expiration is not granular to the record level.